# Java Calendar.roll over DST begin/end has incorrect values

Tags: java, calendar, timezone

This issue occurs when you try to roll over the day when DST begins or ends. For example we can use "America/New_York" timezone set 01/11/2015 to the calendar(the day when EDT changes to EST) and try to roll:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss z");
formatter.setTimeZone(timeZone);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    cal.roll(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
    System.out.println("Formatted  date: " + formatter.format(cal.getTime()));
}
```

This is the result:

...

Formatted  date: 2015.11.01 22:08:32 EST

Formatted  date: 2015.11.01 23:08:32 EST

**Formatted  date: 2015.11.01 01:08:32 EDT**

Formatted  date: 2015.11.01 01:08:32 EST

Formatted  date: 2015.11.01 02:08:32 EST

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `roll` javadoc.

> This default implementation on Calendar just repeatedly calls the version of roll() that rolls by one unit. **This may not always do the right thing.**

[Calendar.roll javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#roll(int,%20int))

If you use `Calendar.add` instead and start on Oct. 31, you will see the correct output --

```
Formatted  date: 2015.10.31 21:33:31 EDT
Formatted  date: 2015.10.31 22:33:31 EDT
Formatted  date: 2015.10.31 23:33:31 EDT
Formatted  date: 2015.11.01 00:33:31 EDT
Formatted  date: 2015.11.01 01:33:31 EDT
Formatted  date: 2015.11.01 01:33:31 EST
Formatted  date: 2015.11.01 02:33:31 EST
Formatted  date: 2015.11.01 03:33:31 EST
```

---

Since you have to use `roll`, add some custom logic to determine the EST rollover point and adjust it accordingly. Its a little hackish, but here is a quick example:

```
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss z");
    formatter.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    boolean isPreviousHour23 = (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == 23);
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        cal.roll(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
        if(isPreviousHour23){
            cal.roll(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1);
        }
        isPreviousHour23 = (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == 23);
        System.out.println("Formatted  date: " + formatter.format(cal.getTime()));
    }
```

Gives you this output:

```
Formatted  date: 2015.11.01 22:24:13 EST
Formatted  date: 2015.11.01 23:24:13 EST
Formatted  date: 2015.11.01 00:24:13 EDT
Formatted  date: 2015.11.01 01:24:13 EDT
Formatted  date: 2015.11.01 01:24:13 EST
Formatted  date: 2015.11.01 02:24:13 EST
Formatted  date: 2015.11.01 03:24:13 EST
Formatted  date: 2015.11.01 04:24:13 EST
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need exactly roll() - not to increase the day

Comment: You will probably have to put in some custom logic to check the EST rollover then... Whenever the time gets around to 00, the EST flag flips and the hour is added. So you would need to check if the previous hour was 23 and EST and set the hour manually (or roll back one?).

Comment: That was my first idea, but I hope to find more simple way. Now it seems to me this is the only way :) Thank you!

Comment: Yep, unfortunately it seems as though the `roll` is not a very solid function.  :(